# How to display all data in 3 columns from a table where the 4th column contains the same ID as another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a site where I have users register into a database table and upon registering, I have a column that generates an AUTO_INCREMENT value labeled ID that assigns to a user.

```
**REGISTRATION TABLE**  
(User info)  ( ID )
```

Once logged in to the site, I allow the user to submit a form that has 3 data fields and a 4th field that is hidden where the 4th field is an echo of their user ID to a separate table named PRODUCTS.

```
**PRODUCTS**

(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)  (echo of ID from REGISTRATION table)
```

I want to be able to give the registered user a confirmation page that displays all the data a user has entered into the PRODUCTS table (the first 3 columns of the PRODUCTS table, not the 4th ID column) so it would like something like this:

“Here are the products you entered:”

```
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
```

where the ID in the PRODUCTS table matches the ID in the REGISTRATION table.

There will be multiple users entering data into the PRODUCTS table where it could look like this:

```
**PRODUCTS**

(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)  ( ID1 )
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)  ( ID2 ) 
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)  ( ID1 )
```

I want to display the data entered ONLY by the current logged in user. 
So if a user has an ID of 1, I want to display all of the entries that have an ID of 1. 
And I want to display the data on a page in either a table or set of DIVs that keep the format of:

```
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
(data 1)  (data 2)  (data 3)
```

Comment: you have taken a lot of trouble to describe your tables in a way that makes it very hard for anyone to try to reproduce the tables locally. it would have been much much easier for you to have jus executed show create table and posted the output here, or pasted output from desc table.

Comment: Also please only tag the relevent RDBMS

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck? Generally you have to use `WHERE` SQL clausule to select only products with given user ID. Then you just iterate through the data to give it desired output.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry, I did not know a better way to ask, I am pretty new to MySQL.

Comment: @Juan-carlos-oropeza Thanks, I will read up on that for future posting, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jan-holas I have the first half working where I can register and login and then submit to the 2nd table. I dont have much experience with formatting data coming from a table and verifying it matches in another table, so I didnt know where to start.

Comment: no worries. I explained instead of down voting because you are new :)

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using select statement

```
select * from products where id = < logged user >
```

Also if u can't send logged user id to this query you can do it using if condition in your html render

but its bad solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
  select id,data1,data2,data3 
  from  REGISTRATION 
  join Products 
  where registraion.id = products.id 
  Order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I will try this and see how it fairs.